# Whitelist a set of properties from a multidimensional json array and delete the rest

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, lodash

For examples sake i'll use a github api response as my data input.

https://api.github.com/users/unsalted/repos

I have a list of properties I want to keep, the rest I want to discard because I want to keep the output i'm generating considerably more compact.

How can I achieve my goal without doing this:

```
      for (var i = tagged.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].owner.gravatar_id;
          delete tagged[i].owner.url;
          delete tagged[i].owner.followers_url;
          delete tagged[i].owners.following_url;
          delete tagged[i].gravatar_id;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;
          delete tagged[i].private;

      };
```

I am using lodash in the project so lodash solutions are more than welcome.

For times sake I didn't fill out the rest of the values but you get the idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given object, you can use `_.pick` to keep only properties that you specify; and then you can map that over your collection.  So, you end up with:

```
tagged = _.map(tagged, function (t) {
    return _.pick(t, ['properties', 'to', 'keep']);
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm on first level properties, I guess i'll just need to call it again on deeper objects.